# Populating database with GDS

Tags: php, mysql

I am planning to operate a php website where users can find and rate hotels.
We can agree that uploading more 10k hotel is a bit too much work and time so my question is, is there any way to populate my database by using a cheap GDS system? I need to upload only once.

Comment: ...and what have you tried so far?

Comment: I am not asking you to do it for me, I just need tips to start somewhere. If it is possible to do (to save to my database with images, and few informations) than probably I will post a related job online.